# one or multiple $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, document

I have a bunch of js snippets each one on separate .js file . gulp is set up to concatenate them all to one `all.js` . which one of below approaches is advised ?

- having each js snippet in separate `$(document).ready` :

  ```
   //all.js

   $(document).ready(function(){
      foo...
   })

    $(document).ready(function(){
      bar...
   })
  ```
- having all snippets in one `$(document).ready`:

  ```
     //all.js

    $(document).ready(function(){
      foo...
      bar...
   })
  ```

Comment: Having one `$(document).ready()` is best in theory, but the performance penalty will be neglectable in practice.

Comment: there is no different, but for avoiding duplicate code, it's better to "having all snippets in one  `$(document).ready` ". if your code has not dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really just a matter of coding convenience or personal style preference.  Either will work just fine and work identically.

Callback functions registered with `$(document).ready()` are called in the order they were registered so even the order will be the same either way.

The performance difference between the two methods is likely so small you couldn't measure it compared to other things going on as it's just a few extra levels of function calls to use two separate `.ready()` calls.  I would be surprised if you could measure the difference and even more surprised if that difference was actually relevant.  It is more likely that you should use other code structure reasons to decide which way to go.

If both functions you want to call are conveniently in the same file, then this will result in more compact code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    foo(...)
    bar(...)
});
```

---

If both functions are maintained separately and/or in different files, then this will fit your code layout more conveniently and allow you to keep independent modules independent of each other:

```
// one place in your code
$(document).ready(function(){
    foo(...)
});

// somewhere else in your code
$(document).ready(function(){
    bar(...)
});
```

In your specific case, you refer to multiple files that are concatenated together.  This means you could use either format.  If those multiple files are meant to be modules that might not all be used together, then you may want each file to "stand on it's own".  If that's the case, then use the 2nd model because the files become independent from each other and any given file can be used by itself.  There would be an advantage to NOT creating a dependency between the two files if no such dependency already existed.

If, on the other hand, the two files are already dependent upon each other and both must be used together in any project, then there is no advantage to trying to maintain any independence so you could use either style just fine.

Remember, for best code reuse or sharing in future projects, testing independence and easiest maintainability, it's useful to make separate files/modules as independent as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically the two approaches are the same. However, there are several points to note.

- A minor performance penalty will be added when using multiple callbacks, but it should be negilible in almost all cases, except for when one adds a really huge amount of separate callbacks.
- While in the current implementation the order is defined by registration order, the order of the callback execution may vary in the future, because in most of such frameworks the handler execution in general is not defined deterministically, so it's a little bit unsafe to rely on the current implementation. It's always better to manually structure the code to ensure that the order of the execution is correct. Of course when all of your handlers are functionally independent, then this is not an issue at all.